# recursive rm -rf of a symlink ?

Tags: symlink, rm

I think I know the answer to this one but I'll ask anyway.

I created a symlink to a dir on a different disk.  A script (which I have no control over) will "rm -rf *" in the dir that has this symlink.  It deletes the symlink OK, but leaves the target dir on the other directory.  I expected this but want to make sure that there's no way I can create the symlink somehow to behave like a hard link in terms of making "rm -rf " recursively delete the dir on the other disk.  -T looked kind of promising, but didn't pan out.  Again, I have no control over the rm command execution.  But I do create the target dir on the other disk, plus I create the symlink to it..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are essentially asking is can a hard link be created across file systems.  The answer is, they cannot.  [This tutorial](http://conqueringthecommandline.com/book/basics#sec-basics-ln-hard) confirms this:

> An important thing to note about hard links is that they only work on the current file system. You can not create a hard link to a file on a different file system. To do that you need to use symbolic links, Section 1.4.3.

As you seem to already understand, removing a softlink will have no effect on the the thing it is linked to.  This is true for hardlinks as well.

Comment: Ya, just like a hard link. Your answer is what I expected.  I just wanted to make sure I didn't leave any stones unturned.  Thanks

Comment: Great @deveg ...glad to help.  Was there anything else?  If not, then the little up arrow and the check mark are awaiting your attention.

Comment: And isn't this a good thing (rhetorical)? Otherwise, you'd have to always worry about a link being somewhere in a subdirectory, when doing `rm -r`, causing God-knows-what to be deleted.